# VS2010 and preventing certain Exceptions being caught by the IDE

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, exception

So...

I've recently switched to .NET4.0 and I'm using VS2010 to develop in.

My scenario is that I have an MVVM WPF application and VS2010 is now pausing and catching the Exceptions being thrown by properties on the VMs when the binding has the ValidateOnExceptions="True" (i.e. I want to throw those Exceptions and they will result in the Validation status changing on the View).

It's really annoying and disruptive to my dev process.

Is there any way to prevent it from doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the menu *Debug -> Exceptions ..* you can choose to break when an exception is thrown, regardless of whether or not it is handled, by checking the *Thrown* check-box. Check the *User-unhandled* to only have the debugger break if that exception is not caught in your code. You can use the *Find..* button to search for specific exceptions that are giving you problems. You can use the *Add..* button to add any exceptions that you have created, but you need the full namespace of your custom exceptions in order for them to be recognized properly.

Comment: Okay. I'm curious as to what best/typical practice is here then... I'm guessing that I should create a custom exception class like UIValidationException and then tell VS2010 to ignore that Exception class?

I find it strange that VS2010 didn't do this when the project was built with .NET 3.5...

Comment: @toadflakz - I don't think this problem is encountered enough to have a _best practice_.

Answer (score 2):

The menu item "Debug" -> "Exceptions" will let you choose which exceptions that should cause the debugger to break.